# Deriving a fixture from derived fixture in googletest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm new to googletest and I'm trying to write unit-test cases in C++ using the googletest framework, the code looks like:

```
class TestInterface : public ::testing::Test
{
    protected:
        static void SetUpTestCase()     
        static void TearDownTestCase()
} ;

class Algo1Interface : public TestInterface
{
  public:
      virtual loadConfig(Inputs, Outputs);
  protected:
      virtual void SetUp()     {  /* Small per test set up */  }
      virtual void TearDown()  {  /* Small per test cleanup */  }
 };
```

Now I need to derive another `Algo...` test interface from the `Algo1Interface` so that I can use the public functions of `Algo1Interface` in a separate test-fixtures.

For example:

```
class Algo2Interface : public Algo1Interface
{
public:
  virtual void SetUp()     {  /* Small per test set up */  }
  virtual void TearDown()  {  /* Small per test cleanup */  }
};
```

So as to write fixture tests like:

```
TEST_F( Algo1Interface, test1_1 )
{
  // Do tests
}

TEST_F( Algo1Interface, test1_2 )
{
  // Do tests
}

TEST_F( Algo2Interface, test2_1 )
{
  // Use the public functions of Algo1Interface class(loadConfig)
  // Do tests
}
```

Question:

1. Can this be done?
2. If so, can anyone explain how to do it?

I have tried researching this problem but could not find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in the obvious fashion. Any class
derived from `::testing::Test` is a googletest fixture; so any class
derived from a fixture is also a fixture.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>


class TestInterface : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    static void TearDownTestCase() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class Algo1Interface : public TestInterface
{
public:
    virtual void loadConfig(std::string const & Inputs, std::string & Outputs) {
        Outputs = Inputs;
    }
protected:
    void SetUp() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    void TearDown() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class Algo2Interface : public Algo1Interface
{
public:
    void SetUp() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    void TearDown() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

TEST_F( Algo1Interface, test1_1 )
{
    ASSERT_EQ(1,1);
}

TEST_F( Algo2Interface, test2_1 )
{
    std::string outputs;
    loadConfig("Config",outputs);
    ASSERT_EQ("Config",outputs);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile, link and run:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -o gtester main.cpp -lgtest -pthread
$ ./gtester 
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test suites.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from Algo1Interface
static void TestInterface::SetUpTestCase()
[ RUN      ] Algo1Interface.test1_1
virtual void Algo1Interface::SetUp()
virtual void Algo1Interface::TearDown()
[       OK ] Algo1Interface.test1_1 (0 ms)
static void TestInterface::TearDownTestCase()
[----------] 1 test from Algo1Interface (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from Algo2Interface
static void TestInterface::SetUpTestCase()
[ RUN      ] Algo2Interface.test2_1
virtual void Algo2Interface::SetUp()
virtual void Algo2Interface::TearDown()
[       OK ] Algo2Interface.test2_1 (0 ms)
static void TestInterface::TearDownTestCase()
[----------] 1 test from Algo2Interface (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test suites ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help